# Java /dev/input/eventX

Tags: java, linux, events, hid

currently I have an N-Trig Multitouch panel hooked to the event file /dev/input/event4, and I am trying [this](https://github.com/progman32/evdev-java) to access it. I have included all of the natives and such in the java.library.path but am getting this error even when superuser. The exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read(FileDispatcherImpl.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:149)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice.readEvent(EventDevice.java:269)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice.access$1(EventDevice.java:265)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice$1.run(EventDevice.java:200)
EVENT:  null
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.asdev.t3.Bootstrap$1.event(Bootstrap.java:41)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice.distributeEvent(EventDevice.java:256)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice.access$2(EventDevice.java:253)
    at com.dgis.input.evdev.EventDevice$1.run(EventDevice.java:201)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I answered this question on the project's [issues page](https://github.com/progman32/evdev-java/issues/1).

> by attilapara
>   Hi, I tried to use this library on a Raspberry Pi and I got the same
>   exception, but I figured out the source of the problem and managed to
>   get it work.      Basically, the problem is that this library is
>   written for 64 bit CPU/OS only. Explanation:
>
> The input_event structure looks like this (source):
>
> ```
> struct input_event {
>     struct timeval time;
>     unsigned short type;
>     unsigned short code;
>     unsigned int value;
> };
> ```
>
> Here we have timeval, which has the following members (source):
>
> ```
> time_t         tv_sec      seconds
> suseconds_t    tv_usec     microseconds
> ```
>
> These two types are represented differently on a 32 bit and a 64 bit
>   system.
>
> The solution:
>
> 1. Change the size of input_event from 24 to 16 bytes:
>
> change line 34 of the source file
>   evdev-java/src/com/dgis/input/evdev/InputEvent.java from this:
>
> ```
>     public static final int STRUCT_SIZE_BYTES = 24; to this:
>
>     public static final int STRUCT_SIZE_BYTES = 16; Change the parse function in the same source file as follows:
>
> public static InputEvent parse(ShortBuffer shortBuffer, String source) throws IOException {
>     InputEvent e = new InputEvent();
>     short a,b,c,d;
>
>     a=shortBuffer.get();
>     b=shortBuffer.get();
>     //c=shortBuffer.get();
>     //d=shortBuffer.get();
>     e.time_sec = (b<<16) | a; //(d<<48) | (c<<32) | (b<<16) | a;
>     a=shortBuffer.get();
>     b=shortBuffer.get();
>     //c=shortBuffer.get();
>     //d=shortBuffer.get();
>     e.time_usec = (b<<16) | a; //(d<<48) | (c<<32) | (b<<16) | a;
>     e.type = shortBuffer.get();
>     e.code = shortBuffer.get();
>     c=shortBuffer.get();
>     d=shortBuffer.get();
>     e.value = (d<<16) | c;
>     e.source = source;
>
>     return e;
> }
> ```